# Prevent Serial.Print to convert data to ASCII

Tags: serial-port, arduino, rxtx, modbus

I would like to create a ModBus-like communication between Arduinos (WITHOUT any RS232/RS485 module). But the **Serial.print(data);** convert data to ASCII Human Readable data. I would like to keep the "Byte" format between arduinos.

Does someone know how to remove this conversion? Is it a simple parameter to change or do I have to create a library?

NOTE: I would like to use a modbus because I have 3 or more arduinos to control.

NOTE: I do not use I2C because I have to control I2C servos on a third Arduino.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function is used to send data in an ASCII encoding; if you want to send the bytes use the `write` function:

http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/write

e.g.

```
char mybuffer[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6};
Serial.write(mybuffer, 5);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am sure I saw it! I'm sorry for such dumb question! :o